# UITableView not loading data on app load // Unable to successfully query related photos for UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I have two issues here.

1) The data in my UITableView does not load when I first open up its ViewController. The proper data does end up appearing, but but only after I add more data to it on another ViewController, and then come back to the TableViewController. Even when doing that, the UITableView is always one item behind, meaning that when I first load the app I will see nothing in my TableView, then if I add an item, for example called "hat" in a second ViewController, I will come back to the TableViewController and see all the items I'd added previously, but I will have to add another item, for example called "chair" to my table in order to see "hat" in my table.

2) While I am able to have users successfully add items to my Parse database and then view the items they've added in the UITableView (albeit with the roadblock addressed in issue 1 above), I am unable to successfully populate the UIImage in each cell in the TableView with the photo file of each cell's corresponding item. The photos are being successfully saved to Parse, so it is definitely a problem querying for them properly, or keying into the exact place they are stored, or simply configuring my subclassed TableViewCell to display them properly.

**ItemsTableViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"giveItem"];
    [query whereKey:@"giver" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.myGiveItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                PFGiveItem *newGiveItem = [[PFGiveItem alloc]init];
                newGiveItem.giveItemName = object[@"giveItemTitle"];

                // return photo files for each of the objecs
                PFFile *giveItemImageFile = object[@"imageFile"];
                [giveItemImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        UIImage *giveItemImageForCell = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        newGiveItem.giveItemImage = giveItemImageForCell;
                    };
                }];
                [self.myGiveItems addObject:newGiveItem];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.myGiveItems.count;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}


- (JFGiveItemCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    JFGiveItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[JFGiveItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    PFGiveItem *giveItem = self.myGiveItems[indexPath.row];
    cell.giveItemLabel.text = giveItem.giveItemName;
    cell.giveItemImageView.image = giveItem.giveItemImage;

    return cell;
}
```

**My Parse backend is structured as follows**

I will be very receptive to any guidance on how to more properly structure my database to be less redundant and more powerful.

*Class 1 "Item" with rows:*

- "itemTitle," a user-input string from the AddItem ViewController
- "owner," the user who adds the item (and photo)
- "itemPhoto," a pointer to an object of Class 2, "ItemPhoto"

*Class 1 "Item" with rows:*

- "imageOwner," the user who adds the item (and photo)
- "imageName," a string the same as the itemTitle from Class 1
- "imageFile," a File uploaded by the user

All of these items are saved successfully, but for your better understanding, here is the code I use to do this.

**AddItemViewController**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *nameForGiveItem = self.giveItemTitleTextField.text;
    NSData *giveItemImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.giveItemImage);
    PFFile *giveItemImageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:nameForGiveItem data:giveItemImageData];
    PFObject *giveItemPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"giveItemPhoto"];
    giveItemPhoto[@"imageOwner"] = [PFUser currentUser];
    giveItemPhoto[@"imageName"] = nameForGiveItem;
    giveItemPhoto[@"imageFile"] = giveItemImageFile;

    [giveItemPhoto saveInBackground];

    PFObject *giveItem = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"giveItem"];
    giveItem[@"giveItemTitle"] = self.giveItemTitleTextField.text;
    giveItem[@"giver"] = [PFUser currentUser];
    [giveItem setObject:giveItemPhoto forKey:@"giveItemPhoto"];
    [giveItem saveInBackground];

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For 1)

In viewWillAppear you call `[self.tableView reloadData];` outside of the block. That means you actually call it before the block has finished executing - meaning before the data was loaded.

Move it to after the for block but make sure it is executed on the main thread - otherwise it will not influence the appearance of the ui - meangin the table will not be acualized either.

For 2)

The solution for 1) should fix 2) as well. You load your images asynchronously, which is perfect. But when that is finished you do not reload the table. When you manage to get it reloaded once all the data has been loaded then the cell images will be refreshed as well.

3)
You may want to add any type of view/spinner/progress indicator or just a regular lable that indicates to the user that some data is still loading ...

Comment: Thanks, Hermann. Existing data now appears in the table when the app first starts up, but if I want to add a new item, I still have to add a second new item to see the first new item (as described in my main post). Any ideas?

Comment: @jaja, well, without seeing the code that adds an item I would guess that there is a similar reason. You will have to update the table after the item was added.

Comment: The code to add an item appears at the bottom of my post. I add items on a separate ViewController; would I update the tableData on that separate view controller? Or would I use a delegate of some sort to do this...